# Under what circumstances will the log of a variable be normal, given that the variable is not normal

Tags: normal-distribution, lognormal-distribution

Let us say there is a variable that is not normally distributed. Under what circumstances will the natural logarithm of the variable be normally distributed?

I have seen many articles and papers where the author will take a logarithm of a variable and the log (x) will be normal. But how to know in advance that if the log(x) will be normal?

Basically, given a non normal variable, do we just keep applying transforms to the variable until we end up with an output variable that is normal?

Comment: This question needs more context to be answerable. You might just as well ask "how to know in advance that a variable $Y$ will be normal?"  ($Y$ merely plays the role that $\log(X)$ does here--both are "variables.")

Comment: I am asking to make a variable normal, do we just keep taking transforms (log,square, square root) until one of these results in a normal distribution?

Comment: Please edit your post so that it asks the question you wish to ask.  That will bring it to the attention of the community so people can quickly decide whether to reopen it or ask for further clarification.

Comment: Consider editing the title, too, to reflect the actual question.

Comment: The keyword you need is "lognormal". Read about lognormal distributions in Wikipedia, in other questions here, ...